# How to create an Axis2 Web Service Client in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, apache-axis, webservice-client

I'd like to use the "Web Service Client" wizard to create a web service client in Eclipse, but the wizard doesn't allow me to choose Axis2 as the web service runtime; I'm stuck with just plain Axis.

I start off at the following screen (which I got to via File -> New -> Other -> Web Service Client ):

[image: Web Service Client dialog screenshot]

I click on "Web service runtime: Apache Axis", to get this new "Client Environment Configuration" dialog:

[image: Client Environment Configuration dialog screenshot]

I've chosen "Apache Axis2", but the OK button is grayed out. Not matter what I choose in this dialog--even if I choose "Apache Axis"--the OK button is grayed out.  I can't get past this step.  Am I using a bad version of Eclipse (Indigo version 20110615-0604 here), do I need to install/upgrade some plugin (I've installed Axis2 Tools 1.1.200v201103022)? What's wrong here?

This is on a Windows 7 64-bit machine.

Comment: Maybe someone will agree that this dialog needs to have some kind of warning or error message explaining WHY the OK button is grayed out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Untill and unless you won't add any server the OK button will be grayed out.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Really?? I have to install a Tomcat server just to use a client?? That doesn't seem right...

Comment: That is the way how eclipse tool behaves,if you don't want all this thing then generate your code in command prompt by setting the AXI2 classpath

Answer (score 6):

Try these, it may help you out to generate a Axis2 web service client successfully, it worked for me.

- Install Axis2 on your system, dowloading from it's site (Google Axis2 download).
- You want to add Axis2 runtime in your eclipse editor : **Windows>>Preferences>>Web services>>Axis2 Preferences**.
- Assuming you are generating web services client in in a **Dynamic Web project**, add Axis2 in **project facets** (right click on the web project >> **Properties>>Project facets**)
- Also add a server run time in your eclipse editor: **Windows>>Preferences>>Server>>Runtime environments**

These should enable your OK button after selecting Axis2 and one of server runtime environments in the **'Client Environment Configuration'** dialog.

Good luck solving your problem.

Comment: It's not a Dynamic Web Project, (what's that?) it's just a console app.

Comment: Why do I have to choose the server?  My server is a WCF server, NOT any Java-related type of web service server.  There's no choice for WCF service in the New Server Runtime Environment dialog.

Comment: Ok, try this link it may help you http://www.kevingao.net/category/wcf-java-interop

Answer (score 3):

Why don't use [Axis2 Code Generator for Eclipse](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/index.html)? I think it'll help you to create client code easier.

Comment: I would if I could get it to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791239/how-to-use-axis2-code-generator-for-eclipse

Comment: Please remember that code generator should have the same version number with axis2 :)