# How to use Axis2 Code Generator for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, code-generation, apache-axis

I installed the Axis2 Code Generator for Eclipse, and am trying to create a Web Service Client.

Here's what I'm filling out in the dialog:

[image]

When I try to submit this, I get an error:

[image]

I only get this error if I check "Create a jar file of codegen result project and add to resulted projected lib folder (...)".  If I don't check this, I don't get any jar files related to my web service, just a bunch of Axis2 dependent jar files.

How do I use the Axis2 Codegen Wizard?

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer **not** to use this generator anymore, this is an old method,
from eclipse Indigo EE, you just go to new--> web service client, and go through the wizard step by step.

Using Axis2 plugins to generate the client and server; you will face a lot of unpredictable issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

Axis2 Code Generator should have same version number with Axis2.