# How to create WSDL to CLient USing JAXB IN STS

Tags: java, web-services

I am Start working on Spring web service but i have donwload the WSDL from w3school web site but when i tried to create client for this WSDL i did not get option of JAXB in SpringSource it only show apache axis and apache axis2 .Please let me know how to generate Web service client from WSDL using springSource.While i have alreay added JAXB plugin is spring source another thing is if i use apache axis2 i i am not able to find service plz help me to understand .

Wsdl is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
      <s:element name="FahrenheitToCelsius">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Fahrenheit" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="FahrenheitToCelsiusResult" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="CelsiusToFahrenheit">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Celsius" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CelsiusToFahrenheitResult" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="string" nillable="true" type="s:string" />
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="FahrenheitToCelsiusSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:FahrenheitToCelsius" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="FahrenheitToCelsiusSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="CelsiusToFahrenheitSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CelsiusToFahrenheit" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="CelsiusToFahrenheitSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="FahrenheitToCelsiusHttpPostIn">
    <wsdl:part name="Fahrenheit" type="s:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="FahrenheitToCelsiusHttpPostOut">
    <wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="CelsiusToFahrenheitHttpPostIn">
    <wsdl:part name="Celsius" type="s:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="CelsiusToFahrenheitHttpPostOut">
    <wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="TempConvertSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="FahrenheitToCelsius">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:FahrenheitToCelsiusSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:FahrenheitToCelsiusSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="CelsiusToFahrenheit">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:CelsiusToFahrenheitSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:CelsiusToFahrenheitSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:portType name="TempConvertHttpPost">
    <wsdl:operation name="FahrenheitToCelsius">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:FahrenheitToCelsiusHttpPostIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:FahrenheitToCelsiusHttpPostOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="CelsiusToFahrenheit">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:CelsiusToFahrenheitHttpPostIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:CelsiusToFahrenheitHttpPostOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="TempConvertSoap" type="tns:TempConvertSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="FahrenheitToCelsius">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/FahrenheitToCelsius" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="CelsiusToFahrenheit">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="TempConvertSoap12" type="tns:TempConvertSoap">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="FahrenheitToCelsius">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/FahrenheitToCelsius" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="CelsiusToFahrenheit">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="TempConvertHttpPost" type="tns:TempConvertHttpPost">
    <http:binding verb="POST" />
    <wsdl:operation name="FahrenheitToCelsius">
      <http:operation location="/FahrenheitToCelsius" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <mime:content type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <mime:mimeXml part="Body" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="CelsiusToFahrenheit">
      <http:operation location="/CelsiusToFahrenheit" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <mime:content type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <mime:mimeXml part="Body" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="TempConvert">
    <wsdl:port name="TempConvertSoap" binding="tns:TempConvertSoap">
      <soap:address location="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="TempConvertSoap12" binding="tns:TempConvertSoap12">
      <soap12:address location="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="TempConvertHttpPost" binding="tns:TempConvertHttpPost">
      <http:address location="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: You're supposed to create a new application and if the tool provide this for you, right click in your project and choose New Web Service Client. I've done this in NetBeans and Eclipse. I haven't worked with STS, but it's eclipse based, so it won't be hard to achieve. For the record, the new application can be a Web or even a Console application.

Comment: but when i tried to creat client it does not provide the option to create using JAXB

Answer (score 1):

JAXB is an API to create Java object from XML or vice versa. Most of the web service  tools uses JAXB internally to parse your wsdl. When you create using eclipse service client, you should see many  generated source file and one of them would be proxy class, and another one represent port type.  Jdk provides API called
Service which you can use to create instance and then invoke service implementation method.

Web service client creation is common across any eclipse IDE, here is some useful links

http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcreate_client.html[1](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html)

[How to create an Axis2 Web Service Client in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782782/how-to-create-an-axis2-web-service-client-in-eclipse)