# Websphere Application Server calls classes from axis jar

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, webserver, web-deployment

I am using JAX-WS to create stub. I have to deploy my EAR file on WAS 7.0.
By default, call to the class is made to the classes in in the axis jar org.apache.axis2.jar which is present in the plugins folder and an error is occured which stops the application to run.
 In the configuration menu I have checked the parent last option and removed the axis jar from the plugins folder.Then the application runs fine.

But now my requirement is to run the application without deleting the org.apache.axis2.jar from the plugins folder.
Is there any way we can make the application run without removing the jar.

Thanks in advance.

Edited after trying aviad's answer:
I am still facing the same problem

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast class     org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.Provider to class javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider
at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:1691)
... 131 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to read [WAS Class loader determination paper.](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp4307.pdf).
You need to use [shared library](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/wasce/V2.1.0/en/shared-library.html) and also define dependency load order inside your EAR.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks aviad, trying from the link you shared. But still facing the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

First idea that comes to mind is generating the stubs for WebSphere webservice framework (which is based on axis2). This works that well that I have projects running axis1 and axis2 webservices together. The job can be done in Eclipse [pretty easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782782/how-to-create-an-axis2-web-service-client-in-eclipse) (or Rational Software Architect / Developer for WebSphere - [available as demo versions as well](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/r/architect/))

Second shot is to change the import in the generated classes. This of course needs a stable WSDL so that classes do not need to be generated on a regular basis. I think it's always a good idea to start with generated classes to finally adapt them to your needs and append additional code by hand.