# Getting error when i try to create webservice clients from WSDL in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, axis, webservice-client

I'm getting below error when i try to create webservice client using WSDL files in Eclipse. I already added required Jars to build path/ but still getting same error. Can someone please let me know what i'm doing wrong.

```
IWAB0503E Unable to update Java build path. Please check your system environment.
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /lib/axis.jar
```

[image: Error image]

I added external jars to build path

[image]

Answer (score 0):

from the exception you get it seems that you have not put axis.jar in the project lib, try checking the build path configuration for the dependencies and verify that they are present in the project lib. There seems to be a misconfiguration of the project paths.

You can also read in this thread an example of how to create a web service client with Axis on Eclipse: [How to create an Axis2 Web Service Client in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782782/how-to-create-an-axis2-web-service-client-in-%20eclipse)

Comment: Hi Alessandrao, I have already added jars to build path as you can see in screen shot. This project has dependencies on 2 other projects which also have axis.jar added to the project buildpath.

Comment: Ok but I think you need to check if your jars are in the lib folder.